# How do I heat up my tent?

Tags: camping, tents

Is there any sort of mini heater that can be powered from a powerbank to be used in a tent (or anything similar)?

Comment: Please give us information about the outside temperature where you are camping and the size of your tent.  For example, if the outside temperature is no lower than the thirties or maybe the twenties (degrees F), and you have a one or two person tent, you (and your companion) are the best heater.   If it is much colder than that and you have a large tent, then the answer will be different (and not one I can help you with, because I have never used a heater.)

Comment: Eskimos use candles in their igloos for both light and heat, but are used very carefully as not to overheat the igloo thus causing the snow to turn to ice and thus make it even colder than before...

Comment: This sounds like an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's the real problem you're trying to solve? Staying warm while you sleep? Staying warm while you're up, but still in the tent?

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate.  Heat up and keep warm for 8 hours is not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did not realize a powerbank was a phone charger.

Even a car battery at 6 amps (that would last like 8 hours) is about 70 watts.  A person puts off about 100 watts.

Even a car battery would not be much of a heater.  Heat is an intense form of energy.

I think you would get about 5 watts from a powerbank and run 8 hours.  Even high capacity is 10 AmpH and the voltage is 3.7.

They have battery powered electric blankets.  That is probably a better option as a tent is not not a good insulator.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean by powerbank something that weighs 200g and has a capacity of 20000mAh and by heat more than a candle worth of warmth, then the answer is no. A 20000mAh powerbank, which is a pretty big phone charger, can source 100 Watts for an hour (ignore for a second that it cannot safely discharge at that rate). [This answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/18374/5836) tells us a candle produces 77 Watts, so a powerbank is like burning a candle for 75 minutes. Space heaters are around 1000W, so you could run a space heater for 6 minutes.

Even if 100Wh was enough for your heating needs, powerbanks are designed to discharge at around 4A (20W), so you would only be able to produce a little heat for a longer time.